# Jenkins pipeline automatic branch detection

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am migrating my old Jenkins free-style job to multi-branch pipeline. I also want to use GitLab hook with them.

My problem is the branch detection. I am doing it manually but I want it to be automatic: when a new branch is pushed to git, GitLab trigger a Jenkins job that trigger the branch detection if the branch parameter from GitLab is not known for Jenkins at the moment. Is this possible to do it or doesn't this exist?

FYI: I tried to launch the multi-branch pipeline job but Jenkins says:

```
ERROR: No parameterized job named XXX found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't receive the answer I wanted and I ran into this issue today that answered the question :

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/298

TLDR: Multi-branch pipeline are not supported yet to be triggered by gitlab commit easily. There is a workaround. Look at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Build Periodcally" in your multibranch job configuration and the branch indexing will automatically started.

Comment: sure but when gitlab will trigger a new commit on a new branch, it will fail because my job will try to find a job generated by the pipeline for this branch which doesn't exist because the branch detection wasn't run.

Comment: How does your include filter for the branches in the multibranch pipeline look then?

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a branch source plugin for GitLab with webhook integration, which is tracked as an RFE in JIRA.

Failing that, use a plain Git branch source and configure GitLab to send Jenkins notifications to `/git/notifyCommit` (IIRC) as documented on the Git plugin wiki. Need specify only a `url`, no other details. The branch indexing this triggers should both detect new or removed branches, and changes to the head of an existing branch, and schedule builds accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set webhook in GitLab for push events and URL like `http://<yourserver>/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>`.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository

GitLab notifies Jenkins on push events which should trigger branch detection also for multibranch pipeline.